# How to automatically Click button during runtime using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created 100 buttons and want to first button clicked by default when page load first time(without clicking on button).

```
HtmlTable myTable = new HtmlTable();
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    for (int c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
    {
        n = (5 * i) + c;
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = n.ToString();
        btn.ID = n.ToString();
        //btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        btn.Width = 30;
        btn.Height = 25;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        cell.Controls.Add(btn);
        row.Controls.Add(cell);
        myTable.Controls.Add(row);
        cell.Attributes.Add("Class", "htTableCellCss");
    }
    row.Attributes.Add("Class", "htTableRowCss");
}
myTable.Attributes.Add("Class", "htTableCss");
btndiv.Controls.Add(myTable);
```

Comment: btn_Click(btndiv.Controls.First(), null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, before you start coding, place yoursef in `protected void Page_Load` method
and there you should just call the onlick method event directly, like this ( lets say yyour button is named myButton, and lets say it's allready defined what's that gonna do):

```
myButton_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

You can place this method invokation exactlly where you need it, so on your page load also

Comment: can you please describe it with my code given above

Comment: thnaks for solution.